# jQuery blocks style

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Here comes a noob question: saw a jQuery code that was written like this:

```
    var PRINCIPAL = {};

PRINCIPAL.Function = function($element) {
    var self = this;
    /*more vars*/

    this.init = function() {
        self.initialFunction();
    };
    this.initialFunction = function() {
        /*code here*/
    };
    this.secondOne = function() {
        /*code here*/
    };
    this.init();
};
    /*associative array below??*/
PRINCIPAL.array = {
    CONFIGURATION: 10,
    CONFIGURATION2: 200,
    init: function($element) {
        /*code here*/
    },
    firstFunction: function() {
        /*code here*/
    },
    secondOne: function() {
        /*code here*/
    },  
    thirdOne: function() {
        /*code here*/
    }
};
/*and at the end it stars all functions inside the blocks*/
$(function() {
    PRINCIPAL.array.init($('#element'));
});
```

Ok, now: there was a lot of arrays(?) like the one above, and some other functions too, all the code was all divided in blocks. I don't get it much, is this a kind of programming style or what?

Comment: in javascript, `{}` denotes an object not an array. all the `function() {}` are anonymous functions, which are used here to store functions in variables to be executed later.

Comment: Re your question "associative array below?" Yes, sort of. Some people (mostly from PHP) call objects "associative arrays," but in JavaScript, the normal term is just "object" or "map" or (rarely) "dictionary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is object notation.  It is not particularly well-written code, though, so you might not want to use it as a learning example.

The general principle, though, is that `{}` denotes an object, so `PRINCIPAL` becomes an object by assignment.  The dot notation allows you to access the object's parameters and methods easily, so the first block defines a method (or function) and the second block a parameter, which in this case is another object.  In this example, the method and parameter have further methods/parameters defined within them, using object literal notation.

[Here's a basic introduction to object-oriented javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, `{}` denotes an object not an array. (But you can think of an object as essentially an associative array or hash.)

All the `function() {}` are anonymous functions, which are used here to store functions in variables to be executed later (functions are just objects and can be stored). `PRINCIPAL.array` here is essentially a pseudo-class, as closures can be used to emulate a class in JavaScript (JS does not have classes built-in).

Answer (score 0):

That is a common (and good) question.

Take a look here: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

Start with 'Named Functions' and work your way down.

The code in your example uses the techniques in this tutorial.
The example, is poorly written, though.